# Auto initializing stucture member to NULL

Tags: c, language-lawyer

My purpose is to make sure that **b** is initialized to NULL.

Standard ISO/IEC 9899:201x clause 6.7.9->10 states

> If an object that has **static** or thread storage duration is not
>   initialized explicitly, then: — if it has **pointer** type, it is
>   initialized to a null pointer;

Below program :

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct A
{
    char* b;
};

int main(void)
{
    static struct A obj;

    if (obj.b==NULL)
        printf(" obj.b auto Initialized\n");

    return 0;
}
```

gave me the output.

```
 obj.b auto Initialized
```

Does this mean that the clause 6.7.9->10 is applicable to all the members of the structure object?

**Note:** Emphasis in the citation are mine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's right, also note the clause regarding aggregate types:

> if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules,
>           and any padding is initialized to zero bits;

This means every member is initialized to zero-value of that type, if the member is another struct, then its members are initialized under the same rule.

Comment: `initialized to zero-value of that type` was classy. +1

Answer (score 3):

> Does this mean that the clause 6.7.9->10 is applicable to all the members of the structure object?

Yes. Sub-objects have the same storage duration as the object they are a member of.

Comment: Please could you quote from the standard?

Comment: @sjsam There's not really any other thing to quote, except perhaps the definition of *object*.  In your code `obj.b` is an object.

Comment: Thankyou ! I see that what I asked it not really a question now :P